# Can a photon move at another speed that's not the speed of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, photons

I was reading an article about the new collider photon-photon, and the writer says "the scientists accelerate photons in a very high speed".

It's non sense to me, because as far I know a photon only moves on the speed of light.

So my question is: **Can a photon move at another speed that's not the speed of light?**

**EDIT:**

This is the article about photon-photon collider:

http://www.theverge.com/2014/5/18/5724658/photon-collider-could-turn-light-into-matter

I found the snippet about accelerating photons at a very high speed in this Portuguese article:

http://meiobit.com/287429/colison-foton-foton-proposta-transformar-luz-em-materia/

Comment: Photons only move with the speed of light. Can you give the link to the article please?

Comment: probably protons not photons

Comment: Photons, not protons

Comment: I put the link of portuguese article in the question

Comment: I don't speak Portuguese well, but the sentence "a colisão de dois fótons a uma velocidade altíssima resultaria na criação de um elétron e um pósitron" seems to phrase the collision as being "high-speed"; it probably was supposed to be "high-energy", but the writer just mixed the words.

Comment: Here is a relevant article about a research team, lead by MIT and Harvard professors, who managed to create a "photon molecule" (as stated in the article). A short excerpt: "Lukin also suggested that the system might one day even be used to create complex three-dimensional structures – such as crystals – wholly out of light."

http://phys.org/news/2013-09-scientists-never-before-seen.html#jCp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to a recent proposal to create matter with pure light (high energy photon-photon collisions):
http://www.nature.com/nphoton/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nphoton.2014.95.html

The article you were reading very likely misinterpreted something or confused "high energy" with "high speed".  Light (in a vacuum) only travels at the speed of light.

Comment: Yeah i'm saying about this article. The writer of portuguese article probably got confused between high energy and high speed?

Comment: Consider the article link I posted in the comment to Lucas' question. It is said that scientists have created a new state of matter from photons and even hope to one day build a 3d structure entirely from light.

Comment: It is a different topic, but very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normally $c$ is for speed of light in vacuum at which light travels at its maximum speed. However if I were to put, say, atmosphere or diamond in from of a light beam, the light would travel slower than $c$, therefore I conclude yes its possible to travel slower than the TRUE speed of light.
Next, to elaborate, in 1905, Einstein's miracle year, he proposed his mass-energy equivalence theory which is $E=mc^2$. This must mean, with some simple rearranging, we understand that mass can be converted in energy and vice-versa. That in mind, a photon is an packet of energy in basic definition. That in mind, we can convert the photons into mass using the formula rearranged: $m=E/c^2$ which means we can even make light travel even at 0 indirectly.